# Create dynamically a vertical button in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a vertical button in PHP, but I have problem with the positioning, when I created a 200px height and 40px width PNG i want to put the text to the center of that image. The text long will be changing dynamically

this is a part of my code

```
$image = imagecreate($this->width , $this->height);
$background = ImageColorAllocate($image, $this->bg_red, $this->bg_grn, $this->bg_blu);
$foreground = ImageColorAllocate($image, $this->red, $this->grn, $this->blu);

if ($this->transparent) ImageColorTransparent($image, $background);
ImageInterlace($image, false);
// render the image
ImageTTFText($image, $this->size, $this->rot, $offset_x, $offset_y, $foreground, $this->font, $this->msg);
```

how can I calculate the `$offset_x` and `$offset_y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation of `imagettftext` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), it

> Returns an array with 8 elements
>   representing four points making the
>   bounding box of the text. The order of
>   the points is lower left, lower right,
>   upper right, upper left. The points
>   are relative to the text regardless of
>   the angle, so "upper left" means in
>   the top left-hand corner when you see
>   the text horizontally. Returns FALSE
>   on error.

So you can first draw the text on another image, just to see what the dimensions will be, then calculate the needed height of your button.